# Variable arguments is not printing

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

```
#define TRACE2(args)   TraceDebug args;

void TraceDebug ( const char * format, ... );

void TraceDebug ( const char * format, ... )
{
  static char buffer[256];
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, format);
  vsprintf (buffer,format, args);
  va_end (args);
}


int main(void)
{
    TRACE2(("ece %d is of %d students.", 1,33));
    return 0;    
}
```

The expected output is `ece 1 is of 33 students.` Why the output screen is blank?

Comment: You fill buffer, but you don't do anything with it, perhaps just a printf("%s\n", buffer); is missing?

Comment: Sidenote: You should favor `vsnprintf` over `vsprintf` to avoid accidental buffer overflows, especially since caller doesn't see the buffer size.

Comment: Your macro is pretty pointless, you can just call your function directly like `TraceDebug("ece %d is of %d students.", 1, 33)`

Comment: @ChrisTurner this technique makes it easier to enable or disable the debugging just by toggling a single define

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only print into `buffer`, but you don't print anything on the screen.

This is what you need:

```
void TraceDebug ( const char * format, ... )
{
  static char buffer[256];
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, format);
  vsprintf (buffer,format, args);
  va_end (args);
  printf("%s", buffer);  // <<< add this
}
```

Or just use `vprintf` if you only want output on the screen.

```
void TraceDebug(const char * format, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);
  vprintf(format, args);  // <<<<<<<<<<<
  va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: if the main is changed like 
`int a = 2, b = 28, c = 55 ;`
`TRACE2((a,b,c));`
it gives `Segmentation fault `.
At this point what i need to do?

Comment: @w.jayson that's rather another question. Basically you get the segfault because you don't provide the a format string such as `"ece %d is of %d students, some other value: %d"`. You need to study `printf`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought vprintf and printf are different.

Comment: @w.jayson err, ther _are_ different. Read the documentation.